# Check calling for some method should belong to Unit Tests

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing

I am trying to follow test a behaviour not a method( that's what i am initially doing). Like i am testing a functionality in which i refresh items from server.

It is basically done in **RefreshItems**() Method. In this method i have some calls to other methods of other service like you can say **NetworkService**(for web request).

As the implementation of RefreshItems may be change or it may not be calling some specific method of NetworkService.

So should my **UnitTests** include a **test** for checking whether NetworkService methods has been called or not ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd check that all necessary calls has been made. When testing RefreshItems, mock the dependent services (like NetworkService) and verify calls have been made.

**Edit:**

Let's say you have an interface and implementation of MyService like this.

```
public interface IMyService
{
    IEnumerable<string> Get();
    void SuperImportantMethod();
}

public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        SuperImportantMethod();
        return new string[] { string.Empty };
    }

    public virtual void SuperImportantMethod()
    {
        // and secret!
    }
}
```

And then MyClass that uses this service, as:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {}

    public MyClass(IMyService service)
    {
        Service = service;
    }
    public void RefreshItems()
    {
        Items = Service.Get();
    }

    public IMyService Service { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could test MyClass `RefreshItems` method isolated from service.

```
[TestMethod]
public void RefreshItemsTest()
{
    var expected = new string[] {"my", "items", "here"};

    var myClass = new MyClass();
    var mock = new Mock<IMyService>();

    mock.Setup(service => service.Get()).Returns(expected);
    myClass.Service = mock.Object;

    myClass.RefreshItems();
    Assert.IsTrue(expected.SequenceEqual(myClass.Items));
}
```

And when testing MyService you can make sure that `SuperImportantMethod` is called every time services "gets" something.

```
[TestClass]
public class MyServiceTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetTest()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<MyService>();
        var service = mock.Object;

        service.Get();
        mock.Verify(s => s.SuperImportantMethod(), Times.Once);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unit Test should not be like this- we should test the behavior not implementation. It may happen that we have to change the implementation of RefreItems then in this case everything will break. we will have a test for call to some method that eventually not exists in new imlementation.

Comment: If you can isolate RefreshItems() and you really do not need to know if NetworkService called some method, then of course you'd leave it out. I revise my answer w/ example.

Answer (score 0):

Inject an interface for the `NetworkService`. It could be called `INetworkService`, but `IItemsService` might surfice:

```
public interface IItemsService
{
    Items GetAllItems(); //or whatever you need
}
```

Then you have two options:

**Mock and Verify**

Inject a mock for that interface and verify the correct calls are called, but as you say this would test the implementation not the behaviour.

```
var itemsService = new Mock<IItemsService>(); //Moq for example
var testObject = new ClassUnderTest(itemsService.Object);
testObject.RefreshItems();
itemsService.Verify(e => e.GetAllItems(), Times.Once); //verify the calls to the moq
```

**Stub**

Create a Stub implementation of `IItemsService` that returns fixed data. Then `Assert` the new state of your class under test.

```
var itemsService = new StubItemsService();
var testObject = new ClassUnderTest(itemsService);
testObject.RefreshItems();
Assert.AreEqual(1, testObject.Items); //some assert on the testObject
```

Note that you can use Moq for stubbing too, rather than create a stub class:

```
var itemsService = new Mock<IItemsService>();
itemsService.Setup(e => e.GetItems()).Returns(/*whatever*/);
var testObject = new ClassUnderTest(itemsService.Object);
testObject.RefreshItems();
Assert.AreEqual(1, testObject.Items); //some assert on the testObject
```

Comment: my question is - should my UnitTests include a separate Test for checking is NetworkService methods has been called or not ?

Comment: Are you asking because it's a network service. i.e. If it was just another class, would you ask that?

Comment: No it can be any class, or some other method.

Comment: my question is realated to UnitTesting approach. i can write unit tests.

Comment: Enough talk, show the code  But is it so that inside Refresh() you call multiple methods of multiple services? If yes, then try to put logic inside dependant services and out of Refresh() method. And when testing services, assert method calls there if it's really needed.

Comment: In my opinion the answer is "No, don't verify". It is rare I feel the need to verify anything. But I'm not going to criticise someone who feels the need to verify that the odd method is called. If you do this routinely that however is a mistake.